# BURG updates, but doesn't show up in boot up GRUB screen

Tags: grub2, burg

I recently updated the Linux kernel (via the Update Manager) to 3.0.0-13.  I am running Ubuntu 11.10 using BURG.

Everything loaded correctly, BURG updated correctly.  But when I reboot, when the GRUB screen comes on the monitor it only reflects 3.0.0-12.

I reloaded the Linux Kernel 3.0.0-13.  Did the "update-burg" (see the results below), rebooted and still it loads GRUB window with the 3.0.0-12 kernel.

What am I doing wrong, or has anyone had this problem?

How do i fix this, I don't want to go mucking around with GRUB as I really don't know that much about it (i.e. manually configuring the GRUB/BURG files).

```
[14:22:52] xxxxxxxx@L01U1110:~$ sudo update-burg
Generating burg.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-13-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 11.04 (11.04) on /dev/sda5
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is slightly confusing, but I would try three things.

- Go into the Software Center and search your version number (3.0.0-12) and uninstall the old kernel.
- If it's BURG that's the problem, you can at least test that it's right by running `burg-emu` in a terminal. Otherwise, make sure that it's also installed on the drive that boots up, which is more than likely the first one:

  > sudo burg-install ("hd0")
  >   sudo update-burg
- Get GRUB Customizer (works with BURG) to manually check and modify which boot items are listed.

  > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
  >   sudo apt-get update
  >   sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

Comment: Sorry about the title.  Let me try to explain.  I did step #2 (burg-emu) and it shows up correctly in a BURG screen.  BUT, when I reboot the window that comes up is a GRUB window, not the BURG window from the (burg-emu).  It's like BURG is installed, but the OS is still looking at GRUB.  I go into GRUB Customizer and it shows both 3.0.0-12 & 3.0.0-13.  For what ever reason BURG is updated to the correct kernel version, but GRUB is not.

Comment: Sounds like burg didn't install to your boot drive, then. Did you try the `burg-install ("hd0")` line? It seems that for some reason, it hasn't overwritten the MBR to load instead of GRUB. I don't know if `hd0` is correct, as I don't know your machine's setup, but I'd imagine you would know if it's different or not.

Comment: BINGO, it worked.  I guess BURG didn't completely install.  But now it is perfect.  THANK YOU so much for your help.  I greatly appreciate it.